# React Native - Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: react-native

**Identification error, how can I define this. It is a map application.**

hedefiKontrol() {

```
let mesafeFarki = (dis[index] / 1000).toFixed(2)); //Error
    
if (mesafeFarki < 0.2) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("SSS");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You've an extra ```)```

Comment: so is that right =>this.setState.mesafeFarki({ mesafeFarki :((dis[index] / 1000).toFixed(2)) });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let mesafeFarki = (dis[index] / 1000).toFixed(2)); //Error
    
if (mesafeFarki < 0.2) {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("SSS");
    
  }
```

You have a extra bracket
and if u want to save it to the state its:

```
this.setState({ mesafeFarki :((dis[index] / 1000).toFixed(2)) });
```